# how can i show 2 annotationveiw on xamarin ios same time

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, maps, xamarin.forms.maps

How can I show 2 annotationveiw on Xamarin iOS map in same time, like arrow head behind vehicle on its previous Lat Long,
I am using custom renderer on iOS but able to display only one image on map am already done in android screen shoot attached.
I am using xamarin.forms.map NuGet want result like this image stuck here from last 20 days [click here for screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4B2a.jpg)

Comment: Do you want to show two icons/images with the same location ?

Comment: No i want to show arrow head on previous latitude longitude and vehicle on current latitude longitude in same time

Comment: Please share your with me idea i want to try it

Comment: You can create two types of pin which shows the different icon ,and add them one by one according to the locations.

Comment: Please suggest me accordingly how can I archive it.